# Why SIGKILL is not handled by my signal handler and sometime leads to account logout

Tags: c, ubuntu, process, kill

I wrote the following code with the following intention:
The child sends SIGKILL signal to the parent and then the parent will handle it using the handler. The handler just increment the counter.

```
int counter = 0;                                                                

void handler(int sig) {                                                         
  counter++;                                                                    
  sleep(1); /* Do some work in the handler */                                   
  return;                                                                       
}                                                                               

int main() {                                                                    
  int i;                                                                        

  //signal(SIGUSR2, handler);                                                   
  signal(SIGKILL, handler);                                                     

  if (fork() == 0) {  /* Child */                                               
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {                                                   
      //kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);                                               
      kill(getppid(), SIGKILL);                                                 
      printf("sent SIGKILL to parent %d\n", getppid());                         
    }                                                                           
    exit(0);                                                                    
  }                                                                             

  wait(NULL);                                                                   
  printf("counter=%d\n", counter);                                              
  exit(0);                                                                      
}
```

However, the first kind of output I get is:

```
sent SIGKILL to parent 8371
sent SIGKILL to parent 8371
sent SIGKILL to parent 8371
sent SIGKILL to parent 8371
sent SIGKILL to parent 8371
Killed
```

Apparently, the SIGKILL kills the parent process. Why does this happen since my handler does not kill the parent?

Another non-deterministic, but very high probability event (~50%) is that on my ubuntu 14.04 64-bit machine. If I execute this code, I will get automatically logout from the account. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Have your read the manual of [`signal()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) ?

First:

> The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also varied historically across different versions of Linux. Avoid its use: use sigaction(2) instead. See Portability below.

Second:

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught or ignored.